# correct way of deleting items from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to use removeValue() to remove items from my database. when i do my app crashes because there obviously becomes a null pointer in the onChange method.

What is the best way to remove Values from the database to stop my app from crashing?

these are the values I'm removing

```
 DatabaseReference detailref = bookingref.child("Bookings").child(customerid);
    detailref.child("Housenumber").removeValue();
    detailref.child("Address").removeValue();
    detailref.child("Postcode").removeValue();
    detailref.child("Phone").removeValue();
    detailref.child("Date").removeValue();
```

and in another activity, i call them using a value event Listener.

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()!=0){
                house = dataSnapshot.child("Housenumber").getValue().toString();
                address = dataSnapshot.child("Address").getValue().toString();
                postcode = dataSnapshot.child("Postcode").getValue().toString();
                phone = dataSnapshot.child("Phone").getValue().toString();
                date = dataSnapshot.child("Date").getValue().toString();
```

here is the null pointer error from my Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at studios.p9p.h20.showroomfinish_adminapp.Booking_details$4.onDataChange
```

Comment: `getValue()` will return null if there is no data at the requested location.  You need to check for that.

Comment: i know the reason but how can i check for this?

Comment: Just like any other null check in Java.

Comment: I'll also point out that your question in the title talks about how to delete things, but none of the code you're showing is deleting anything. You are only showing the handling of some query, whose results are missing. It seems to me that you perhaps did delete things correctly and you just want to check to see if they are actually deleted? I'm not clear.

Comment: thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please put more details of what are you trying to do?
I think it's crashing because you're removing values separately. If you're trying to remove all the child data, you could try something like

```
 DatabaseReference detailref = bookingref.child("Bookings").child(customerid);
 detailref.removeValue();
```

If not, maybe you could check if it exist before you try to get the values...
Not the best or beautiful way to to it, but it may work...

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  if(dataSnapshot.exists()
     {
        if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()!=0){
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("Housenumber")
           {
            house = dataSnapshot.child("Housenumber").getValue().toString();
            }
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("Address")
            {
            address = dataSnapshot.child("Address").getValue().toString();
            }
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("Postcode")
            {
            postcode = dataSnapshot.child("Postcode").getValue().toString();
            }
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("Phone")
            {
            phone = dataSnapshot.child("Phone").getValue().toString();
            }
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("Date")
            {
            date = dataSnapshot.child("Date").getValue().toString();
            }
     } }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: brill it worked see my answer below on how i used it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i used the answer above but in a much simpler way. i created a firebase model with all my strings in it called bookingModel() then in side my ondataChange() i could change all the bulky code below :)

```
house = dataSnapshot.child("Housenumber").getValue().toString();
address = dataSnapshot.child("Address").getValue().toString();
postcode = dataSnapshot.child("Postcode").getValue().toString();
phone = dataSnapshot.child("Phone").getValue().toString();
date = dataSnapshot.child("Date").getValue().toString();
```

id already got a userid string for the ref node called customerId
so i used this instead in my onDataChanged()

```
if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(customerId))
bookingModel firebase_model = 
dataSnapshot.child(customerId).getValue(bookingModel.class)
```

then to delete i call

```
detailRef.child(customerId).removeValue();
```